# Intermittent recurring ping general failure to internet but not router

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping

I have found very few posts that fit my exact scenario, but the ones I've found don't have helpful answers. (Like this one: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/ping-general-failure-to-internet-intermittent-and/964e959b-ec91-43dc-a5ec-f97240050a4f)

The specific problem is that one Windows 7 desktop loses internet access. When it loses internet access, pinging any ip beyond the gateway returns a general failure, but pinging the router and any internal IPs works fine. You can also access the router's web interface, so all network functions seems to be working on the local network, just not across the internet.

Over the last week it happened a couple of times, but is getting more frequent. At first restarting would "fix" it for a while, but now most of the time it's failing.

McAfee is installed.

So far I've tried:

- Disabled McAfee services
- disabled IPv6
- reset winsock and tcpip (netsh commands)

Tomorrow I'm going to try uninstalling McAfee and using the McAfee removal tool. Completely reinstalling is not an option due to software on the machine.

Any pointers or suggestions or tools/utilities to troubleshoot this would be appreciated!

---

**Update:** In this case it did seem to be caused by McAfee because it's been working fine since McAfee was removed. I'd like an answer that includes tools, utilities and techniques to determine what is causing this sort of problem so in the future I'm not just rolling the dice and uninstalling software to see if that fixes it. (Unless that is the only way to diagnose this sort of issue)

Comment: I've uninstalled McAfee and had to use the McAfee removal tool, the normal uninstaller wouldn't run. So far it's working, I'll update this for posterity in a day or two.