# General failure while pinging my router

Tags: networking, router

I have been having a problem with my router connection in the last few weeks(i've noticed that after a router replacement by the ISP because of another problem).

The problem is that when I try to ping my router's IP, I get an error from time to time of "General failure".

[image]

and my laptop is connected WIRED, and tried to replace the cable.

I've posted similiarly post few weeks ago but alot is changed and all the description was wrong(So deleted the last one)

well, i've searched for answers all over the internet and did not find any solution.

Yes - i've updated my drivers to the latest one - the problem is keep happen.

one thing I noticed, is that its happening NOT ONLY in my laptop, its happening from time to time on another laptop that connected wired to the router, so I can understand from that maybe the problem is on the router(its happening while i'm pinging the router).

EDIT:

Tried to disable IPv6 on my pc with big hope it will help, but unfurtunatley it doesnt.
I have looked up at my router logs, and here is what I saw in the log view when my pc experienced the issue:

[image]

I just want to mention that, its a new router that I've received from my ISP.

My router is:  Technicolor - MediaAccess TG789vac v2

Software Version: 17.1

Firmware Version: 17.1.7998-0001023-20190124124851

I tried to restore my router to the factory defaults and it keeps happen (on both laptops).

EDIT:

There is a sniffing record by Wireshark when the issue occure:

http://ge.tt/5AmHx633

Yes the record is around 1500 lines, its after filtering.
its happened while I tried to ping google's DNS.
The last ping before the issue was on line 10 and the next one was one 1327, between them the issue is occure.

Comment: What are you pinging... The router itself (gateway address) or something on the internet? If you are failing pings to the router, especially on multiple devices, then the likely culprit is the router itself or anything else in common like if you have a switch between the router and network devices.

Comment: I'm pinging my router, sry for not mention that.

I'll update that on the question

Comment: what do you mean "general failure". Quote the message. Better, Show the output. Do you mean like https://i.imgur.com/Ppju6Zw.png

Comment: @barlop nope, added a screen shot to the question.

Comment: You say yourself this only happened since changing router. Maybe it's an issue with the router

Comment: I don't think there's a setting on a router for "let pings to the IP fail from time to time", or any setting that'd be expected to cause that. I suggest you try speaking to your ISP about it

Comment: @barlop you are right, I didnt thought its some setting, but asked to be sure its not a problem on the firmware of somthing like that. I'll check it with my ISP, Thanks very much

Comment: This is not uncommon when your IP version is incorrect... Are you using IPv6? If not, try disabling it in Windows.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks, I tried that with big hope and unfortunately it keep happen.    Updated with new details from the log view in the router managment in the question under EDIT.

Comment: @GuyCohen if you want more clues you could use a packet sniffer like wireshark, and filter for ping (known as ICMP protocol), and for the source and dest IPs of your computer and your router.  But do you still have your old broken router and is it the same model?  'cos if your old broken router doesn't have that problem but your new one does then that should suggest to you it's a router issue

Comment: @acejavelin no it can't be that, look his error is that sometimes he gets a reply and sometimes not.  I doubt that happens in the situation you suggest. He is getting some replies and they have an IPv4 address, so he has IPv4 set up on both.

Comment: You could check if this problem exists on every port of the 'router'

Comment: @barlop Yes, i've already have a sniffing data of that issue. when I look over the ICMP and over that packets, there is no any clues(just stop pinging and continue when the issue is over), but there is alot of another data but cant understand this data.

Comment: You could include screenshots of that in your question.. what does your ISP say if/when you mentioned this issue? Just because it's a new router doesn't mean it's not faulty. It's good to have more than one router incase one goes down, as internet access is important. And generally for troubleshooting it's good to have more than one of stuff.

Comment: @barlop I tried to change port on my router (again with big big hope, and unfortunately... no magic), but I've tried to change again, at the time we speak(to the desktop port that works fine, and still the problem occure).
But I can tell that there is a another Desktop computer that connect via bridge if I call it in the right name (somthing that connected to router port and splitting that port to more 4 devices).

on that desktop computer, according to my tests, the issue is not happening there. (its windows 7 there).

On the laptops windows 10 (if it matters).

Comment: @barlop its too large to take a screenshot of it, its 1500 lines(!!!), after filtering all other packets (before and after the issue).
I dont know if it possible, I maybe upload it to the question?

Comment: @GuyCohen maybe that port that that desktop is connected to, is one port of the 'router' that is working.  What you call a bridge, some call a switch, there isn't a big difference between a switch and a bridge

Comment: @GuyCohen well, you could in theory use http://ge.tt to upload the file, but really it's probably a router issue, what does your ISP think about it? They don't really make these things easy for people to investigate 'cos what happens inside the router is a bit of an unknown.. Some people have routers where the router software is very open.. like DDWRT or something like that and then some people dig around. Some will even set up a little computer as a router, then they can dig around.

Comment: @barlop sorry for delaying in with my answers, I try things at the time we speak.
I've updated the wireshark sniffing data to the question post.
To be honest I didnt mentioned that yet In front of my ISP, till yesterday I tought it was only "My laptop problem", and yesterday I discovered its in other latop that connected directly but I will talk to them about that.

Comment: @barlop

One more thing, as you suggested, I tried to disconnect that bridge/switch and connect only the desktop computer directly to the router to check if it fix the issue, and for the last 5-7 minutes, there is no problem(good news), but I keep waiting.

Comment: @barlop Wow, it had a feeling like I find the problem... but... just heppen right now :(
the other switch I've talked about is disconnected and on my hand, so everything is connected correctly, but issue still there.

Comment: @GuyCohen You are limited in what troubleshooting you can do because you only have the one router.  The ISP probably won't go through the wireshark data.. The issue you are seeing is very rare.. intermittent general failure when pinging. e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/907863/intermittent-recurring-ping-general-failure-to-internet-but-not-router    and even that problem isn't the same as yours.

Comment: Why not just see if the ISP will replace the router... If you are curious re computers there are so many different areas you could look at where you would learn stuff. With likely hardware related issues like this people just try swapping the hardware.

Comment: @barlop You are right. I asked here the question, just to be sure i'm not missing anything with this problem just before blaming the ISP  I will talk to them soon and hope for good.

Comment: @GuyCohen it is not about blaming the ISP. The ISP have tech support troubleshooters like you or me that may even give you ideas of what to try out.  And their knowledge is very specific to this area as all their calls are troubleshooting internet issues.

Comment: @barlop yes you are right. I was talking to them today, and they changed some settings on the router, for one hour it seems the issue is solved, but instead of "general failure", there is two lines of "request time out".

Comment: @GuyCohen It would be very very interesting if you post as an answer, what you learnt as an answer here, that may then lead to another question or a later edit of your answer. Hopefully you remember the troubleshooting steps you did with them. If not it's good to take notes. Maybe you can change settings to reproduce and then solve the problem so as to turn the general failure into a request timeout. And we may then be better placed to finding the answer to the request timeout.

Comment: @barlop The problem unfortunately is not solved at the end of the day.
I was testing it all the time from then... altoug the settings change the ISP did to the router.
I talked to them again after the issue is returned again, and they will send me a technician is going to test the problem pysically at the place. they said, maybe its aa problem inside the router.
The technician should come tommorrow, I will update with the solutions after that, ofcourse.

Thanks

Comment: @GuyCohen thanks, please update with the solution so far though that changed general failure to request timeout.  And the troubleshooting steps they mentioned.  It may be useful for others. And then a further update when you hear from the technician This site works as a QnA database pooling knowledge of expert users / techs.

Comment: @barlop I dont really know what they did, it was a settings change they did remotely.
And the general failure is back again, so it dont really helped.

Today the technician should come and I'll check with him what he does and ofcourse update this answer.

Comment: @GuyCohen ah re remote working, generally speaking i'd suggest that you don't let them do stuff themselves on your computer 'cos you wont' learn anything. Tell them you want to do it and you want them to help you do it by telling you what to do.  Then, they may say "open the command prompt",e.t.c. in which case you have have a conversation easily. Or if you are unlucky they may talk in baby steps and say "click here / click there/ "(leading you to open a command prompt), and then you have to speed them up.  Make sure they know you know how to do xyz.

Comment: @GuyCohen so you could let them see your screen(though that's optional). Infact it's probably better if they don't see your screen 'cos then they give you more information about what you are to look for to troubleshoot as they are.   Really at your level of knowledge on a computer, there's no reason why they can't talk you through things.  and ask you what you see. And then you can ask them questions too to see what they are looking for and why something matters.

Comment: @GuyCohen Remote suppose is suitable for very low skilled end users that can barely use a mouse, and users that just aren't technical at all..  If they try it on you then just tell them no you want to do it can they help/support you in fixing it.    BTW they are called technical support (not technical take-over and do everything for you - unless you need that, which you don't)! You can learn a lot from them if you use them right. (less so if they are very unskilled and don't know even the basics).

Comment: @barlop You are absolutly right. but I dont know why they just "do stuff" even if I introduce my self as "with knowledge".
btw There is an update about this issue, I will update it as "Answer".
They replaced me a new router, and the issue still happennig, the technician said, it should be some infastructer issue (inside my house), so they should continue working on it.

Comment: @GuyCohen it's like chess, saying you are "with knowledge" isn't the right thing to say.. you want to stop them going straight in so best to say to them as I suggested so they dont really have a choice in the matter. And they can support people so it won't be a problem for them.  They can't do stuff remotely on your computer unless you tell them they can.

Comment: @GuyCohen They might even say "well if you 'have knowledge' or don't want me to go in then why are you calling / what do you expect me to do".So u have to tell them in an idiot proof way that you want them to help you fix it - you fixing it, with their support. They'll understand.

Comment: @GuyCohen Have you tried pinging when wireless? What happens then? And if wireless works, then how about if one computer pings another through the router?  And how about if you connect 2 computers up with a cable directly and each pings each other?

Comment: @barlop The settings they changed, wasn't in my computer, they changed some settings on the router remotely, but you are right.
Well, with wireless, then I dont experience the issue in the same way, with wireless, its just "kicking" me from the wifi, and I need to reconnect.
If i connect 2 computers with cable and ping each other, so intermittently they lose connection with that issue, and ofcourse the ping is going to lost.
Tommorrow i'm going to check all my infastructor in my house plus talking to my ISP for some infastructor fixing in my house.

Comment: @barlop the technician said... because my wired telephon in my house is "riding" on the same infastructor as the internet(the service is comming from different companies, the telephone from one and the internet from another). so he suggest me to split that to 2 pairs instead of one pair either for the telephone and the internet, because he thinking this causing the problem.

Comment: @GuyCohen from a conversation I had with tech at my ISP once, they said that  all phone sockets in the house, should have a microfilter in them.  He also spoke of a way to test for noise on the line.. But, I don't see how it's possible for that to be related to your problem beause you are talking about going straight from computer to router, not even through the internet. You could perhaps disconnect the internet cable and still have private 192.x.y.x or 10.x.y.z addresses and try pinging

Comment: @GuyCohen I haven't heard of that .. I'd have thought most people have phone and internet from different companeis.. ISPs are rarely phone companies. Be interesting to see where their diagnosing goes

Comment: @barlop Yea, here we can split it to different companies, but its work in special way... same infastracture with differenct companies, now we are requested to them to split the infastructor, different to phone and different to internet.

by the way, there is new thing I've learned on this problem, hold tight on somthing so you dont fall.
I did a test, DISCONNECTED MY ROUTER FROM ANY INFASTRACTURE, CONNECTED ONLY ELECTRICITY, PINGED MY ROUTER AND THE PROBLEM IS STILL HEPPENING!!
means, it comes from the router... but.... they just replaced my router... and same problem!

Comment: It just make me crazy.... I wrote a letter to the router's company "technicolor" support, for maybe them can help me.

Comment: @GuyCohen yeah disconnecting it from the wall is a good test.. it's what I meant when I said "disconnect the internet cable"!    Some interesting tests you can suggest to the tech guy.. What if they at their office from their laptop, ping one of their technicolour routers(ie locally at their office). Do they get the error you get? If so, then there you go. If not then what if they then take that router and their laptop to your place.  Then ping it(locally from your place), do they get the error. If so, then that can be investigated (e.g. is it the power in your home! who knows..!)..(cntd)

Comment: @GuyCohen  (Cntd)  If they don't get the error then you can then try pinging the router they brought in, but from your laptop. See if you get the error or not.

Comment: @GuyCohen also try getting a completely different manufacturer of cables. It's really cheap to replace cables. It just helps to rule things out. And while you are at it, you can look at if there is a different in wireless/wifi issue between the router they brought in and the one they replaced it with.

Comment: @GuyCohen also maybe you can google "quiet line test" there are different ways of doing it, it may vary from country to country.In some theere may b a number to call. .Or u can disconnect a connector..there r tutorials on that..In  Eretz HaKodesh may have its ways!  My ISP is Zen in the UK, they are pretty good and any router they use is usually reliable and they have used technicolor routers so technicolor routers might not b that unreliable.generally.Sometimes an ISP with 24/7 tech support can be useful but then the quality of the tech (like level 1 or 2),can b low until they move u up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107976/discussion-between-barlop-and-guy-cohen).

Comment: @barlop Sent you an update on the chat about the problem issue.
Finnaly solved the problem!!
I'll Update my answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI, it's a really bad idea to use an ISP provided router, and if one must be used, you should place your own router between the ISP router and your devices.  ISPs retain SSH access to their routers for troubleshooting consumer issues, however the customer is then exposed to at least two types of data breaches: (1) rogue employees abusing their SSH access privileges; (2) an external data breach of the ISP's system(s) that may never become public, even if it's known about by the ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution via another similar case, resulting with no ping reply failure:

1. **Device Manager** > **Network Adapters**
2. Right-click **Ethernet adapter** > **Properties** > **Advanced**
3. Disable:

   - Energy Efficient Ethernet [Green Energy]
   - Wake on Magic Packet

Comment: Thanks for that update and posting the answer.. By the way, If that's the case then had you done one of the early suggestions of connecting two computers together with an ethernet cable and pinging each other, you'd have eliminated the router early on from the problem!.  Or getting a network switch and connecting computers to that. (i.e. not involving the router of course).  Those suggestions were very much to try eliminating the router!

Comment: . Also that probably happened after a very set period of inactivity.   When you see an intermittent problem it's important to find the trigger.. And one test is to wait x period of time and see if a period of time makes a difference.  So that's another "learning" one can learn from this.